# jQuery - CSS property in variable does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to set CSS properties by a variable:
e.g.
{background: red; }

My code has a mistake, it does not work: [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UeRL4/)

js

```
            var Key = 'background';
            var Value = 'yellow';


                $('.test').css({

                    Key: Value
                });
```

Comment: this kind of syntax may require the **exact** string like as CSS code you type (which does not support any kind of variable), so use other kind of syntax provided by the answers below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like `.css("propertyname","value")`. So your code will need to change like

```
$('.test').css(Key, Value);
```

See [this](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for more reference

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
$('.test').css(Key, Value);
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UeRL4/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

See there are two ways of applying css to an element with jQuery:

### First:

```
$(selector).css("propertyname","value");
```

### Second:

```
$(selector).css({"propertyname":"value"}); // object with key : value pair
```

---

What is the issue in your code?

The issue is

```
{Key:Value}
```

object key which has to be a string *("")* so that does not work in your case your best bet to go with first one:

```
$('.test').css(Key, Value);
```

to understand this go to this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xj95/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the plain object `css` overload, then you will need to do it like this:

```
$('.test').css({
'background': Value
});
```

Or

```
var properties ={};
var Key = 'background';
var Value = 'yellow';

properties[Key] = Value;

$('.test').css(properties);
```

The problem with `{Key: Value}` is that it thinks the property name is `Key` and not `background`.